# CS7038: Failed to emit module in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

While building the ASP.NET Core project, I am getting folllowing error.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Source Suppression State
Error E:\ITFundaCorp\Development\IndianConsumerComplaints\ICC.Web\src\ICC.Web\error CS7038: Failed to emit module 'ICC.Web'. ICC.Web C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets 262 Build

I noticed that this started coming when I added MailKit and System.Drawing.Premetive references into project.json.

Now, even if I removed those references I am keep getting this.

Any expert help?

Answer (score 0):

After i added some code in one of my test project, I got the same error "Failed to emit module {projectname}" for one of my test project. I found very few helps in the net. So, i started to debug in old way to remove recently added test, and add back one line at a tie. Then what i discover is one of my configuration was not returning right value.

```
     var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                     .Configure(app =>
    if (context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("identity", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return await context.Response.WriteAsync("Test response");
    }
...
```

Return should not be there and the error i was getting was "Faileed to emit module...". Hope it helps someone